# replace duplicate values in a list with white space

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Say I have a **sorted** list, and I want to keep each value in the list for once.

```
a = ['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'bb', 'cc']
```

shall be converted into

```
a = ['aa', ' ', ' ', 'bb', ' ', 'cc']
```

It seems to be a very odd request. The reason behind this is I want a unique label list for my seaborn heatmap for xticklabel. The length of my list is very long (>1000). If I plot every value in my list, the plot will be a disaster.

Comment: Not difficult.Could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: @CSY do you need those empty values for some reason? or just need unique values in your list?

Comment: @GopinathS If I do not put empty values there (only unique labels), I have to specify the position to put those labels, which is inconvenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list is sorted, the simplest is to use `itertools.groupby` to convert every subsequence, then stitch them together:

```
from itertools import groupby

new_a = [x for k, v in groupby(a) for x in [k] + [' '] * (sum(1 for __ in v) - 1)]
```

Comment: a succint answer.

Comment: ... that had an error. :) sorry about that. I knew I put those parentheses in for a reason, then forgot to actually subtract 1...

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach with easier readability.

```
org = None
a = ['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'bb', 'cc']

for i in range(len(a)):

  if a[i] == org:
      a[i] = " "

  else:
      org = a[i]
      
print(a)
```

Output:

```
['aa', ' ', ' ', 'bb', ' ', 'cc']
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use counters

```
In [26]: a
Out[26]: ['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'bb', 'cc']

In [27]: from collections import Counter

In [28]: data = []

In [29]: for i in counter:
    ...:     data.append(i)
    ...:     data.extend([" "] * (counter[i] - 1))
    ...:
    ...:

In [30]: data
Out[30]: ['aa', ' ', ' ', 'bb', ' ', 'cc']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['aa', 'aa', 'aa', 'bb', 'bb', 'cc']
newlist = []
for i in a:
    if i not in newlist:
        newlist.append(i)

    else:
        newlist.append('')

print(newlist)
```

```
>> ['aa', '', '', 'bb', '', 'cc']
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create a new list,

```
new_a = []
```

Then, ignore all the other occurrences of that particular element and replace it with whitespaces

```
for i in a: 
    if i not in new_a: 
    new_a.append(i)
else:
    new_a.append(" ")

print(new_a)
```

Output :

```
>> ['aa', ' ', ' ', 'bb', ' ', 'cc']
```